# I need to construct Kolmogorov Smirnov test for exponential distribution, but I don't know how to get rate of the given data in R

Tags: r

So, I need to construct ks test for exponential distribution, but when I tried to specify the parameters for the exponential distribution: "rate(data)" it states that there is no such function, for normal distribution I could use sd(data) and mean(data), but I don't know how to attain the rate of the given data in R. Can someone help?

```
ks_test <-  function(n){
  data2 <-  rexp(n)
  st <-  sqrt(n)*(ks.test(data2, "pexp", 1/mean(data2))$statistic)
  return(st)
}
n <-  1000
N <- 10000
ks_stat <-  replicate(N,ks_test(n))
hist(ks_stat, breaks = 25, col = "orange", prob = TRUE)
lines(density(ks_stat),col = "black", lwd = 2)
```

Comment: Typo? You declare `dati` but reference `data`. (Otherwise, `data` is a base function in R. If you've defined `data` externally to the function, then it's often bad practice to "reach out" from the function to a variable that is not explicitly defined in or passed to the function.)

Comment: Also, `Error: could not find function "rate"`. I think you meant `rate=dati`.

Comment: @r2evans But that's the question. I need to get rate from some data that are exponentially distributed so that I could use it as a parameter within ks.test function and I don't know how to get it.

Comment: (1) Is `data` defined as a variable somewhere? If to, you need to tell us. (2) `rate` is not a function that I've found. If you know that it is a function somewhere, then you need to provide it. What am I misinterpreting?

Comment: The problem remains, though I'll update it for the current version of your code: ***where is `data2` defined?*** Not in the function, so that's certainly a problem/bug.

Comment: @r2evans I edited my post once more. I have a  data frame and I wan't to test if it's distributed exponentially, for that I need to construct the ks. test and as arguments I need to place the parameters for the specific distribution, and for exponential it would be rate? So, how do I get the rate of the particular given distribution? I tried to do it as 1/mean(data2$x) but that gave me totally incoherent histogram.

Comment: @r2evans Data2 is just simply data frame loaded into r.

Comment: Yes ... and using data that is neither passed-to nor defined-within a function *is bad practice*. It renders the function not-reproducible (and to me, unreliable) because the same inputs do not guarantee the same outputs (since the same inputs give no indication of what `data2` contains). I certainly cannot reproduce this question, since I have no idea what type of data this function is using.

Comment: Outside of R, how do you find the "rate" of exponentially-distributed data? Isn't this just "curve-fitting", in which case you should regress to find what you think the distribution is?

Comment: @r2evans Yes, I need to find the distribution for the data. And I need to construct the ks test, but it only works for normal distribution, I guess, so I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: The test has nothing to do this with initially, since ... once you know how to calculate the *rate*, you will then run a KS-test or anything else given that knowledge. And no, since the KS-test is non-parametric, it has no assumptions of normality.

Comment: @r2evans Ok, when I simply generate data from exponential distribution and then try to check for the correct distribution it works, but in case I have a data of 32 data points, how can I check in a similar way for multiple distributions? I tried to do it with drawing just sample of 10 but then it just does it 1 time and I get a histogram that is totally even, maybe in case of having a one sample it shouldn't be done with simulations?

Comment: You can manually iterate through various parameters. You can `optim`ize (or `optimize`) for the parameters. There is no easy *"just find it for me"* function that I'm aware of.